# python: can't open file 'Functions.py': [Errno 2

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to run my sample code containing functions but get the following error when running from the command line.

> python: can't open file 'Functions.py': [Errno 2

I have checked my environment variables and also reviewed my code. I am currently using JetBrains Pycharm 2018.3.2 version, could this be the issue?

Comment: what are you typing in the cmd?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Hereunder is the code and the command on CMD

def My1st():
    firstVar = 1
    secondVar = 2
    result = firstVar + secondVar
    print("The result is " + result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    My1st()

C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\FirstProJec>python Functions.py

Comment: Please edit your answer to add this additional info as it makes it easier for others to see and answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, your code should be like this:

```
def My1st():
    firstVar = 1
    secondVar = 2
    result = firstVar + secondVar
    print("The result is ", result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    My1st()
```

Notice the concatenation in the `print` statement and the name attribute.
and then if you're on windows(as it looks like you are),

```
py Functions.py
```

should give you the output: 3

Comment: I have made the change, but still get the same result. Could this be an issue with the environment?

Comment: @SamuelMasemola Probably no, how are you running the file now? Right click on the file (opened in the pyCharm) and click on `Run 'Functions.py'` and what do you get?

Comment: I have sorted the issue out now. 
The problem initially was when creating the file in the IDE using the Pycharm  wizard and clicking on File instead of selecting Python File. Noticed this after directly checking the directory. 
Thank you all so much for the assistance and hope to provide more valuable input in future as I continue to learn and grow with Python :)

Comment: @SamuelMasemola cheers, you can mark the answer and close the question if it helped!

Answer (score 0):

`Errno 2` points out at a file or directory not being found (in this case 'Functions.py'). Could you check whether your path to Functions.py is correct?

Comment: Hi, I have checked the path. Tried using the command line and the IDE Terminal which both produce the same result. This is the path below.

(venv) C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\FirstProJec>python Functions.py

Answer (score 0):

there was an error in below line of your code

> print("The result is " + result)

the problem is that you can't concatenate **string** with **int** value

and also i am not able to understand you problem but below are some code that you may want from your problem statement.

```
def My1st():
    firstVar = 1
    secondVar = 2
    result = firstVar + secondVar
    print("The result is ", result)
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    My1st()
```

**OR**

```
def My1st():
    firstVar = 1
    secondVar = 2
    result = firstVar + secondVar
    print("The result is ", result)

My1st()
```